# isomorphism $\mathfrak{m}\otimes_A (A/\mathfrak{m})\cong\mathfrak{m}_\mathfrak{m}\otimes_{A_\mathfrak{m}}(A_\mathfrak{m} / \mathfrak{m}_\mathfrak{m})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a commutative ring and let $\mathfrak{m}$ be a maximal ideal. Then $A_\mathfrak{m}$ is a local ring with maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}_\mathfrak{m}$.

There is a field  homomorphism $A / \mathfrak{m} \to A_\mathfrak{m} / \mathfrak{m}_\mathfrak{m}$ and it is isomorphism.

**I want to prove that
$$\mathfrak{m} \otimes_A (A / \mathfrak{m}) \cong \mathfrak{m}_\mathfrak{m} \otimes_{A_\mathfrak{m}} (A_\mathfrak{m} / \mathfrak{m}_\mathfrak{m}) \tag{*}$$**

**as $A/\mathfrak{m}$- vector space.**

---

My attempt(you can ignore it since the proof is not very good): I can construct the homomorphism explicitly as:

$$\mathfrak{m} \otimes_A (A / \mathfrak{m}) \to \mathfrak{m}_\mathfrak{m} \otimes_{A_\mathfrak{m}} (A_\mathfrak{m} / \mathfrak{m}_\mathfrak{m}) \\ x\otimes_A a \mapsto \varphi(x)\otimes_{A_\mathfrak{m}} \varphi(a)$$
where $x\in \mathfrak{m}, a \in A/\mathfrak{m}$, and $\varphi:A \to A_{\mathfrak{m}} $ is the canonical map into the localization, it will induced the isomorphism $\varphi :A/\mathfrak{m} \to A_{\mathfrak{m}}/\mathfrak{m}_{\mathfrak{m}}$.

To see (*) surjective since $\mathfrak{m}_\mathfrak{m} = \varphi(\mathfrak{m})\cdot A_{\mathfrak{m}}$ via the extension operation. therefore the elementary tensor in $\mathfrak{m}_\mathfrak{m} \otimes_{A_\mathfrak{m}} (A_\mathfrak{m} / \mathfrak{m}_\mathfrak{m})$ is of the form $\varphi(x)\cdot a \otimes_{A_\mathfrak{m}} \bar{b}$ for $a \in A_m$ and $\bar{b} \in A_m/\mathfrak{m}_m$ therefore it lies in the image of $$x\otimes_A\varphi^{-1}(\overline{a\cdot b})\mapsto \varphi (x)\cdot a \otimes \bar{b}$$

Therefore it's surjective.

---

I think my proof is not very satisfactory , I believe there is better proof for the fact (*)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in a couple smaller, bite-sized pieces: $\newcommand\m{\mathfrak{m}}$

1. $\m_\m\otimes_{A_\m} (A_\m/\m_\m)\cong (\m \otimes_A A_\m)\otimes_{A_\m} (A_\m/\m_\m)$ since $S^{-1}M\cong S^{-1}R\otimes_R M$ for any ring $R$, module $M$, and multiplicatively closed subset $S$
2. $(\m \otimes_A A_\m)\otimes_{A_\m} (A_\m/\m_\m) \cong \m \otimes_A (A_\m\otimes_{A_\m} (A_\m/\m_\m))$ by associativity of the tensor product
3. $\m \otimes_A (A_\m\otimes_{A_\m} (A_\m/\m_\m)) \cong \m \otimes_A (A_\m/\m_\m)$ since $R\otimes_RM\cong M$
4. $A_\m/\m_\m\cong (A/\m)_\m$ since localization is exact
5. $(A/\m)_\m\cong A/\m$ since elements not in $\m$ already act invertibly on $A/\m$.

Comment: Thank you for your great answer @Hank Scorpio, do you use the fact that $A / \mathfrak{m} \to A_\mathfrak{m} / \mathfrak{m}_\mathfrak{m}
$ is isomorphism explicitly?

Comment: Oh I see step 4 and 5 prove this result, very clear solution thank you!